# linearity of an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

I want to understand the linearity of an inner product.
  Let's say I have a linear operator $S_U:V\rightarrow V$, $\forall v\in V \ S_U(v)=2w-v$  such that $w$ is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $U\subset V$ .

I am trying to calculate $\langle S_U(v)\ | \ S_U(u)\rangle$ for two vectors $u,v \in V$.

by definition of $S_U$ I can write $\langle 2w_1 - v\ | \ 2w_2 -
 u\rangle$ such that $w_1$ is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $U$ and $w_2$ is the orthogonal projection of $u$ onto $U$.

Then, by lineraity of the inner product **can I write**:

$\langle 2w_1 - v\ | \ 2w_2 -
 u\rangle = \langle 2w_1\ | \ 2w_2 \rangle - \langle v\ | \ 2w_2 \rangle  -\langle 2w_1\ | \ u \rangle +\langle v\ | \ u \rangle $
**?**

Comment: Inner products aren't linear, they are either _sesquilinear_ (over $\mathbb{C}$) or _bilinear_ (over $\mathbb{R}$). In either case, you computation is correct. Is that all you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product is a **bilinear** function. This means that it is linear in both its two arguments, so we have:
$$
\langle 2w_1 - v\ | \ 2w_2 -
 u\rangle = \langle 2w_1\ | \ 2w_2-u \rangle - \langle v\ | \ 2w_2-u \rangle= \langle 2w_1\ | \ 2w_2 \rangle   -\langle 2w_1\ | \ u \rangle - \langle v\ | \ 2w_2 \rangle +\langle v\ | \ u \rangle 
$$
as you have found.

Comment: Can I then use the field commutative property and use bilinearity again to get $\langle 2w_1 - v\ | \ 2w_2 -
 u\rangle = \langle v \ | \ u \rangle$ ?

Comment: No. This is true only if $4\langle w_1\ | \ w_2 \rangle   -2\langle w_1\ | \ u \rangle - 2\langle v\ | \ w_2 \rangle=0$